# Difference between $numpages & $max_page on archive pages

Tags: archives, globals, paged

After taking a look at `global $max_page;` and `global $numpages;` on category-archive pages (`is_archive() || $GLOBALS['wp_query']->is_archive` returning `true`), I see the following return values:

- `$numpages`: 4
- `$max_page`: 7

What's going on here?

Further Qs:

1. Where do they come from? After looking into /wp-includes/query.php I found `$numpages` in `setup_postdata()`, but beeing called as `global` on top and later counts the pages by the array that get's exploded through the `<!-- nextpage -->`-array.
2. `$multipage` get's set to `0` if the `$post->post_content` is already an array. Why is this in this case set to `0`, as the array indicates that it should be multipaged? Plus: Where could the array come from? post_content saves as string...
3. Why do I have `$numpages` on archive templates/pages as it is only meant to be set for paged content types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's go through variables one by one:

1. `$numpages` is set on each `setup_postdata()` call. It becomes either `1` or number of pages in multipage post.
2. `$max_page` doesn't seem to be global at all. I don't see it referenced as such in code and from quick test it is not getting set on archive page for me.
3. `$multipage` indicates if current post has multiple pages (in other words if `$numpages` is larger than `1`).

> Where do they come from?

Mostly `setup_postdata()` as you have discovered.

> `$multipage` get's set to `0` if the `$post->post_content` is already an array

It does not. It gets set to `0` if `$post->post_content` does not contain any `<!--nextpage-->`.

> Why do I have `$numpages` on archive templates/pages as it is only meant to be set for paged content types?

Because any loop sets it (in `setup_postdata()` call) and it remains set. It's like calling something after the loop that was not reset - globals still hold whatever post that was looped through last.

Comment: Ah, yea. Haven't thought about the fact that globals won't get reseted to zero (why should it). And `global $max_page` was my own failure. I needed a query var to be global to make it accessible in some other class and therefore put `$GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages` into `global $max_page`. :) If you want, you can close it as "too localized".